# How to get a discord bot to output everything user inputs instead of just the first input?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to get a bot that will repeat what a user inputs, as many times as the user specifies.
The issue I'm running into is that if the user types: `!repeat 5 x y`, the bot will only repeat `x` 5 times, and not `x y` 5 times.

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
@bot.command()
async def repeat(times: int, content="Repeating..."):
    for i in range(times):
        if times > 10:
            await bot.say("Cannot spam more than 10 messages at a time.")
            return
        else:
            await bot.say(content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the  [keyword-only argument syntax](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments) and do something like

```
@bot.command()
async def repeat(times: int, *,content="Repeating..."):
  for i in range(times):
    if times > 10:
      await bot.say("Cannot spam more than 10 messages at a time.")
      return
    else:
      await bot.say(content)
```