# How do I put multiple words in one argument discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am working on a bot that uses discord.py, and I want to have a command that lets you set the game the bot is playing, but I don't know how to make an argument that allows spaces.

I have tried to make 2 arguments, but then if you want **one** word it will show up as an error.

```py
@client.command()
async def game(gameplay):
    #do things
```

I want the argument "gameplay" to have multiple words in it. Can someone please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a discord bot to output everything user inputs instead of just the first input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54384797/how-to-get-a-discord-bot-to-output-everything-user-inputs-instead-of-just-the-fi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@client.command()
async def game(ctx, *args):
    # args contains all arguments written after the command i.e !game game i want to play
    # print(" ".join(args[:])) will print "game i want to play"
```

As you can see in the example, `*args` will contain everything written after the command. ctx will be the context. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why make a copy of `args` with `[:]`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Honest to god till you just mentioned it I have not thought about it twice. You're right that's not necessary unless you want to omit part of the array, which I ususally have done, hence me just copy pasting the `args[:]` and removing the index.

Answer (score 2):

```
@client.command()
async def game(ctx, *, args):
    ctx.send(args)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.