# Bot only takes one command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot where when you type for example "!say hello world" and the bot would reply with "Hello World". But when I try to do spaces it doesn't work.

So when I simply type "!say Hello" it shows this:

[image]

As you can see it works fine but when I put a space for example "!say hello world" it shows this:

[image]

As you can see it only prints "Hello" and acts like I didn't say "World".

Here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def say(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55665255/how-do-i-put-multiple-words-in-one-argument-discord-py help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here: [Commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html)

Since positional arguments are just regular Python arguments, you can have as many as you want:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg1, arg2):
    await ctx.send('You passed {} and {}'.format(arg1, arg2))
```

Sometimes you want users to pass in an undetermined number of parameters. The library supports this similar to how variable list parameters are done in Python:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, *args):
    await ctx.send('{} arguments: {}'.format(len(args), ', '.join(args)))
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, it worked! I appreciate you for helping me. Have a nice day and stay safe :)