# Send a multi-word message in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So I pretty much want to have a command that is formed like this

`!reply {id of a ticket} {and the message}`

but every time I type a command like for example "`!reply XXXXX Test 1`" only the "Test" part gets send and "1" doesn't.

```py
@bot.command()
async def reply(ctx,id,message):
    found = False

    with open('data.json','r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    for entry in data:
        if entry["message_id"] == id:

            found = True
            user_id = entry["user_id"]
            user = await bot.fetch_user(user_id)

            emb = discord.Embed(title=message)


            await DMChannel.send(user,embed=emb)
            await ctx.send("replied to user")

    if found == False:
        await ctx.send("This id doesn't exist or has already been answered")
```

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) Please see [ask] and [help/on-topic]. What is `message`? How do you get it? Please [edit] your post to include a [mre].

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the code in plain text. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55669391/16136190) should help. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code. StackOverflow shouldn't be the first place to ask such questions. Search for these on Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=discord.py+take+sentence+as+argument.

Comment: What do you mean to do when you do `DMChannel.send(user, embed=emb)`? Are you trying to call that from the class itself?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your arguments to `async def reply(ctx,id, *, message):` That should do the trick.