# How would I go about making a discord.py ReasonConverter?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am working on a bot in discord.py, and for the moderation sections I have to have the users provide a lot of "reason" arguments, consisting of one variable-length string, which I am currently doing like so:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Moderation(commands.Cog):
   def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
      self.bot = bot

   async def ban(self, member: discord.Member, *reasons: str):
      reason = " ".join(reasons)
      # and ban them...
```

However, this feels unclean and clunky, and I think there may be a better way using converters. No online guides I found show how to make a converter that takes more then one argument though.

I have tried creating a ReasonConverter like so:

```py
class ReasonConverter(commands.Converter);
   async def convert(self, ctx, reason: str):
      ...
```

But this only operates on one singular argument, and when giving a reason with spaces in it each word is treated as a separate argument.

Comment: What about `async def convert(self, ctx, *, reason: str):`?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how that would change the fact that all of the separate words in the message are passed as different arguments, could you please make an answer so that I can understand what you mean?

Comment: I think your combination was wrong. Check out the following and let me know if that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55665255/how-do-i-put-multiple-words-in-one-argument-discord-py
Your question is very unclear for me at this point.