# In discord.py how can I set multiple words as one argument, but still require the user to put in an argument?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, I'm not sure if the title is readable, but basically I want to set up a mute command.
In which you can put multiple words for a reason, but also it should require you to put the argument in there as a kind of failsafe.

This is what i currently have:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True) #checking permissions
async def mute(ctx, member:discord.Member, *args):
...
reason = ' '.join(args)
...
await member.send(f"You have been muted because of {reason}")
```

But if someone fails to put in a reason, I don't want the command to execute and instead trigger the MissingRequiredArgument error. Before I had it setup so that you only could write in 1 word as an argument or put it in quotes or something. Which did succeed in the way that the user needed to put in an argument, but I do want it to work with the current way.
Is that possible? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a discord bot to output everything user inputs instead of just the first input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54384797/how-to-get-a-discord-bot-to-output-everything-user-inputs-instead-of-just-the-fi)

Comment: You can also just try to `print(args)` when the parameter is unused to see what it looks like without input. Then put a condition that raises an error if `args` matches that input. That's what I would do to test but I'm on mobile right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html), you would instead use `*, args`. Below is the code from the docs.

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, *, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)
```

[image: Keyword-only Argument]

Comment: works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```py
if reason in ['', ' ', None]: raise MissingRequiredArgument
```

You can try that above the send line. You can also do what the other user said and also make the arg parameter `arg=None` so that it will always be `None` unless someone types more. And if it's None, do something similar to what I wrote above.

Comment: just tried this, and it also does work, however the above solution works too and is a lot more simple. thank you nonetheless for your help!

Comment: No problem, glad you solved it :]